# How to sort a list of objects in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a list of items that will be shown to user. I know to sort the items I can send the list to back-end, sort them and show them again but how to do it in front-end so no need to send the list to back-end.

Ive found [this table](https://www.datatables.net/) but it shows the results in columns. As you see I want to show them in a specific way as following.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${products}">
                    <div style="text-align: left;">
                      <div>
                         Name: ${item.name}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        Price: ${item.price}
                      </div>
                   </div>
                 --------------------------
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
</div>
```

The output is not a table it would be like following

```
Name: item1
Price: 12
---------------
Name: item2
Price: 23
----------------
```

Comment: get the list items sorted out before displaying .

Comment: @jegadees at first need to show them unsorted  then allow user to sort them. Also have different types of sorts. please vote up to attract more viewers.

Comment: @jegadees sort by name / sort by price. please click on this table link in the question for further details.

Comment: search for jquery table sorter

Comment: @Mahesh that is based on columns but I do not have any column here.

Comment: you can do manually sorting with jquery .. link for the ref:   http://community.sitepoint.com/t/sort-div-order-alphabetically-based-on-contents/39955/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the elements, take a look the example I did to sort by number:

http://jsfiddle.net/tnnqyxcw/1/

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
        if(s === 0){
            $(this).data('sort', 1);
            $('.clist div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.sid < b.dataset.sid
            }).appendTo('.clist')            
        }else{
            $(this).data('sort', 0);
            $('.clist div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid
            }).appendTo('.clist')
        }
    });
});
```

Html

```
<button data-sort="0">Sort:</button><br>
<div class="clist">
    <div data-sid=1>Number 1</div>
    <div data-sid=4>Number 4</div>
    <div data-sid=3>Number 3</div>
    <div data-sid=1>Number 1</div>
    <div data-sid=4>Number 4</div>
    <div data-sid=2>Number 2</div>
    <div data-sid=1>Number 1</div>
</div>
```

So you can use `data-` to sort for all you want and then assign the click to the button or whatever you want.

I hope it's help.

Comment: I accepted your answer, however I have some problems with it, you may find the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269812/how-to-have-a-relational-table-with-two-primary-keys-in-hibernate Thanks.

Comment: @Jack I saw your new question just now.. sorry for the delay.

Comment: No worries man, I just wanted you to answer that to get the points. thanks