# Can only sort divs if they do not have many tags in their bodies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items that need to sort them. The answer in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246769/how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-in-jsp/29250526#29250526) partially solved the issue. The items in the code that has some tags in thier `<div data-sid=xx>` tags do not get sorted and their styles stop working.

In demo you can see by clicking on "Sort By Price" button the items wont get sorted and their background colors will get changed, but as soon as I replace the tags with single `<h1>` tags it works.

This version of code has some tags as body of its `<div data-sid=xxx>` tags.

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/f8w1hpj2/1/)

**Does not work**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
     <button id="price" data-sort="0">Sort by Price:</button><br>
<button id="name" data-sort="0">Sort by Name:</button><br>

        <div id= "row" class="row">
            <div id="items" class="col-md-7">
            <div class="clist">
                <div data-sid=12>  <<many tags in its body
                    <a href="www.example.com?id=1">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: green;">
                            <div>
                                Name:
                                <h1>Demo1</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div>Price:12</div>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div data-sid=13>
                    <a href="www.example.com?id=2">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: green;">
                            <div>
                                Name:
                                <h1>Demo2</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div>Price:13</div>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                <div data-sid=1>
                    <a href="www.example.com?id=3">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left; background-color: green;">
                            <div>
                                Name:
                                <h1>Demo3</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div>Price:1</div>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#price').on('click', function(){
        var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
        if(s === 0){
            $(this).data('sort', 1);
            $('.clist div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.sid < b.dataset.sid
            }).appendTo('.clist')            
        }else{
            $(this).data('sort', 0);
            $('.clist div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.sid > b.dataset.sid
            }).appendTo('.clist')
        }
    });

        $('#name').on('click', function(){
        var s = $(this).data('sort'); console.log(s);
        if(s === 0){
            $(this).data('sort', 1);
            $('.clist div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.name < b.dataset.name
            }).appendTo('.clist')            
        }else{
            $(this).data('sort', 0);
            $('.clist div').sort(function(a,b){
               return a.dataset.name > b.dataset.name
            }).appendTo('.clist')
        }
    });
});
</script>

    <footer> </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see this code just has single  tags in body of its `<div data-sid=xx>` tags.

**Works**

```
        <div id= "row" class="row">
            <div id="items" class="col-md-7">
            <div class="clist">
                <div data-sid=12> <<<< just one tag in its body
                <h1>12</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-sid=13>
                    <h1>13</h1>
                    </div>
                <div data-sid=1>
                <h1>1</h1>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-sid="12">
<div data-sid="13">
<div data-sid="1">
```

Missing apostrophes.

```
 $('.clist > div').sort(function(a,b){})
```

Change the queries in your JavaScript to only sort direct child elements, not their contents - that breaks the sorting mechanism you need (try clicking sort in your demo several times and watch how the UI order of text starts bugging out).

You also have no `name` data-attribute added to the elements, which breaks the second sorting button logic that is trying to use it.

Fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/f8w1hpj2/2/